# Artisanal whaling!? When did the use of artisanal start being used for activities not involving making fine products?

Tags: phrases, expressions, history

[Wikipedia, Omura's whale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omura%27s_whale#SIze) uses the phrase **Artisanal Whaling** to describe hunting of whales by natives in the vicinity of the Mindanao Sea.

> **Artisanal whaling**
>
> As early as the late 19th century, the natives of Lila, Bohol, began
>   hunting whales in the Bohol Sea...

I am familiar with the extension of artisanal from furniture and other fine products to foods especially bread, cheese, wine, and beer, but was surprised to see artisanal applied to hunting.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/artisan) says of **artisan**:

> Today, when factories produce almost all of our goods, artisans
>   usually make only fine objects for those who can afford them. And we
>   now even include food among the artisan's crafts, so you can buy
>   artisanal cheeses, breads, and chocolates—but probably not if you're
>   watching your budget.

Obviously, *artisanal X* is X produced by artisans.

I found a reference to [artisanal mining](https://phys.org/news/2017-05-congo-miners-resort-wildlife-food.html)

> The new study titled "The socio-economics of artisanal mining and
>   bushmeat hunting around protected areas.....

and also a reference to [artisanal fishing](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44125685?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

> Hunting for Tuna and Cash in the Solomons: A Rebirth of Artisanal
>   Fishing in Malaita

**My question:  when did artisanal expand from production of fine objects to activities such as hunting?**  Is there any indication that artisanal is expanding further outward to include, say, artisanal jewel thefts a la *Ocean's Eight?*

The question [Artisanal, what is its modern cultural history](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53526/artisanal-what-is-its-modern-cultural-history) does not satisfactorily address my question, because it focusses on products such as artisanal cheeses and has only one brief reference to artisanal fishing.

Comment: Dunno, but some months back the waitress at Baker's Square was bragging about their artesian bread.

Comment: It has crossed into buzzword territory, which means it'll just get thrown at anything and everything until it has no meaning anymore. Then the marketers will move on to the next word, and the next, until every descriptor in the English language has been rendered useless.

Comment: "Artisan: a person skilled in an applied art; a craftsperson." [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/artisan). Since when is it restricted to food products?

Comment: I’m pretty sure there *is* an art to harpoon throwing...

Comment: @Jim There is a great deal of skill, approaching art, required for lots of things, for example driving a dog sled.  Artisanal mushers?

Comment: Not to mention gathering the tribe to process the thing on the shore. Artisanal in contrast to industrial. Artisanal has never carried the connotation of finery, only skilled workmanship and perhaps some specialized process knowledge and tools. Which isn't to say that it doesn't sometimes seem really weird  - " The Furtive-eGT is an artisanal electric supercar with range extender...."

Comment: Yeah, in my mind the current use of Artisanal connotes production using processes that don’t scale usually involving actual “hands-on” by people with specific crafting skills.

Comment: *artisanal*:  **(of a product, especially food or drink) made in a traditional or non-mechanized way.** ODO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **artisanal hunting**, the earliest mention of could find:

**Ecological Development in the Humid Tropics**  [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=7Ofi6GgsJKoC&q=%22artisanal%20hunting%22&dq=%22artisanal%20hunting%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiop9nMvc_cAhUqw4MKHRwnBo0Q6AEISzAG) 1988

> Such forests have had human impacts restricted to low levels of
>   **artisanal hunting** and fishing and harvesting of forest products

As you mentioned, artisanal mining is noted ~ 80 years earlier. To your question:  **When did artisanal expand from production of fine objects to activities such as hunting?** I am guessing the latter part of the 20th century.

As far as expanding outward?  Take a peek at these and gird thy artisanal loins:

**11 surprising artisanal careers that are taking off**  [mother nature network](https://www.mnn.com/money/sustainable-business-practices/stories/11-surprising-artisanal-careers-are-taking)

and

**10 Fascinating Artisan Crafts**  [listverse.com](https://listverse.com/2011/11/21/10-fascinating-artisan-crafts/)

A *food waste artisan*, an *artisanal ice cubes*, *artisanal pyrography* (also known as pokerwork or wood burning) and more.  I found a quick 20 in these last 2 articles.  It is exploding in the 21st century!

Comment: ["artisanal mining"](https://books.google.com/books?id=-1ALAAAAYAAJ&q=%22artisanal%22&dq=%22artisanal%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirj8f6wM_cAhWM24MKHVCvD0EQ6AEIMjAC) 1904